# how to make multiple numbers of bootstrap cards if a condition is met?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

I want to make multiple numbers of bootstrap 4 cards. let's just say: i have one card, now i want to make more cards but without hard code. i want to make these cards automatically if a condition met.using jinja2 for loop. in these case `if my_var == 10`, then i want to make 10 more bootstrap cards. else do something else. how do i achieve that. PLEASE help.

```
{% set my_var  = 10 %}

<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
        <div class="card-deck">
            {% if my_var == 10 %}
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/img/rename.svg') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." width="150" height="200">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{x[0]['bookname']}}</h5>
                    <p id="text-card">Description: {{v}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small>Donated by: {{x[0]['donatedby']}}</small></p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-pill"> <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> Request</a>
                </div>
            {% else %}
            {{v}}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```